# Is group by 1 a standard SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by

Is group by 1 a standard SQL?

The SQL like this:

```
select c_name, count(1) as number from table_one group by 1
```

This SQL is right in MySQL. But I want to know that can it work in SQL server or Oracle? I do not have SQL server or oracle service, please help me.

Comment: You can use [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to experiment.

Comment: No, it's not valid standard SQL. According to ANSI/ISQ SQL, you are only allowed to specify columns in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: SQL Server - NO. Oracle - NO!